# R filter raster using focal() with threshold - defining correct function

Tags: r, filter, raster, threshold

I have the issue of defining the right function for my task. For filtering an image I have set up a filter matrix eucdis with

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
refm=matrix(1,nrow=11,ncol=11)
M = dim(refm)[1]

N = dim(refm)[2]

eucdis = matrix(NaN, nrow=11, ncol=11)
for (i in -5:5){
      for (j in -5:5){
            eucdis[i+6,j+6] = 2*(sqrt(sum(abs(0-i)^2+abs(0-j)^2))) #euclidean distance of the moving matrix
            eucdis[6,6]=1
            eucdis[eucdis>10]=0
            eucdis[eucdis>0]=1
      }
}
```

Using the example raster

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
f
r <- raster(f)
```

I want to filter all values of that raster that have a certain value, say 200 within 10%  (=8) of the moving eucdis filter matrix

```
s=focal(x=r,w=eucdis,fun=function(w) {if (length(w[w==1])>=8) {s=1} else {s=0}})
```

But this only gives me all values where the eucdis filter matrix has at least 8 pixel with any values of r. If I add the constraint about `r[r>=200]` it is not working as I thought it would. It is not taking the second constraint into account.

```
s=focal(x=r,w=eucdis,fun=function(w,x) {
           if (length(w[w==1])>=8 | x[x>=200]){s=1} else {s=0}}) 
# I also tried & and &&
```

If anyone can help me please. I have spend days already and can't figure it out my self.

Thank you,

Anne

Comment: Could you please clarify what "200 within 10% (=8)"  means?

Comment: Oh sorry that this is not clearly written. The raster value 200 or more shall be the constraint and this value shall be valid for at least 8 pixel of that moving matrix. If this is valid, then the center pixel is set to 1. If these constraints are not fulfilled the center pixel shall be 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to `focal` doesn't refer to the weights matrix. Rather, it refers to the cells of `r` that fall within the moving window (and these cells' relative contribution to the function's return value is controlled by the weights matrix). So, where you have used `function(w) {if (length(w[w==1])>=8) 1 else 0}`, you're actually saying that you want to return 1 if the focal subset of `r` has at least 8 cells with value equal to 1 (and return 0 otherwise).

One to achieve your aim is to perform a focal sum on a binary raster that has been thresholded at 200. The function that you would apply to the moving window would be `sum`, and the output of this focal sum would indicate the number of cells of your thresholded raster that have value 1 (this corresponds to the number of cells of `r` that have value >= 200 within the moving window).

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))

m <- matrix(2 * pointDistance(expand.grid(-5:5, -5:5), c(0, 0), lonlat=FALSE),
            ncol=11, nrow=11)
m <- m <= 10

r2 <- focal(r >= 200, m, sum, na.rm=TRUE, pad=TRUE)
plot(r2)
```

[image]

You can then check which cells of that raster have value >= 8.

```
r3 <- r2 >= 8
plot(r3)
```

[image]

In this case, almost all the cells meet your criteria.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is really helpful. But unfortunately this blurs the edges. The problem is that the center pixel will be set valid also if only pixel at the edge of the matrix m fulfill the constraints.

My other idea was to introduce a third constraint (but this is way too advanced for me). That all 8 pixel must be connected with N8 relationship among each other and also the center pixel shall be involved. Do you have an idea of how to introduce this issue?

Thanks again! Anne